# Echo Elements by class Name

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

Let's say that i have more a href elements with different class names on a page "tst.php" like this:

```
<a class='1' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='3' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='4' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='1 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='1 4' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='2 3' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='2 1' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 6' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 6 7' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 5 7 8 9 4 6 2 6' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
```

i want to make a php code that will echo in another page "echo.php" onli the a href's elements that have class name 2 in their values.

Something Like this

```
<?php
$stream = readfile("tst.php");
$regex = "class= '2'"
preg_match_all($regex,$Text,$Match);
echo $Match all;
?>
```

And the echo should be only the Href's that are class named with "2":

```
<a class='2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='1 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='2 3' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 6' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 6 7' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
<a class='5 2 5 7 8 9 4 6 2 6' href='etc.html'>Link</a>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842 - use xpath or some other sort of built in XML/HTML parser in PHP

Comment: put the links in a db, make life easy for yourself

Comment: Why are you doing this in PHP instead of Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: is esear for my to have access to tst.php amd make changes. and the echo.php just showing my changes!

Comment: Or mabe is somting similer to wath i want to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You shouldn't use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You should use tools designed for this like [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Here's a basic example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($string_with_html);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $class = $anchor->getAttribute('class');
    if (strstr($class, '2')) {
        echo $dom->saveHTML($anchor) . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/S8vM6L)

You could also use [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($string_with_html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$anchors = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@class,"2")]');
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
     echo $dom->saveHTML($anchor) . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: lets say that i need this to work olso in div elements!

Comment: This gets you most of the way there. You should be able to convert this to use DIVs easily.

Comment: how to echo the result! ive tried somting but no luck. i'm new in php!

Comment: What are you trying to echo?

Comment: becose i have multiple a href and i want to be able to select witch one to apear in the webpage from tst.php like a sorting procidure!

Comment: In both examples the first item in the loop will be what you need. So you can do whatever you want to that element (echo it out, modify it, etc) and then end the loop.

Comment: i did echo $anchors; insted of // do something but no result!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have all of the pieces of your code I need, or the time I need, to make a full working demo. The code I posted is 95% of what you need though. Hopefully playing with it for a bit will help you work out the remaining details.

Comment: i just nedd to echo all a hrefs elemnts that have 2 as class name.

Comment: @user3329634 I've updated my answer to echo out the anchors that match

Comment: how to echo only first result?